# In python 3 print() command to print chr with ascii directly under in a complete table

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to python and want to use it as retirement project. However I have a lot of trouble trying to print a table in the format below. I only will show the ascii table as below, in what I'm trying to achieve

```
chr:      !   "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   / 
asc: 32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  46  47 
chr:  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   :   ;   <   =   >   ? 
asc: 48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
```

I tried `'\n'` in many variations and I cannot print the output as above. Here is the short code I tried to get the thing working at least;

```
for asc in range(32,64):
        print(chr(asc),end = ' ')
        print(ord(chr(asc)),end = ' ')
```

Putting a `'\n'` in anywhere, only confuses the issue further;

```
for asc in range(32,64):
        print(chr(asc),'\n',end = ' ')
        print(ord(chr(asc)),end = ' ')
```

Makes the output vertical again, so I'm stuck. I looked hard on Google and this site and I would prefer to stay away from class type commands as I'm still at the very beginning of programming. The long way at this point. Any help would be welcome.

Comment: Sorry the table above is confusing. I mean to show the chr with the related ascii directly beneath (next line). The above did not post as I expected.

Comment: You can always press the 'edit' button and fix the table, @Robert.

Comment: Indentation is still wacked

Comment: You're trying to print the character, then the code below it, for each character. This won't work. Instead, print all the characters, then, with a separate `for` loop, print all the codes.

Comment: I'm sure you've noticed that the trick to what you're trying to do is to get the padding correct depending on the number of characters you're printing. You will need to write some logic to check the number of characters you are printing for each entry in `chr` and match that number of characters in `asc`. That will involve seperating the calculation of your spacing, storing that, and then passing that information to another function which handles the printing. What other programming experience do you have?

Comment: Actually, I need to go with the exact way as I indicated above. I have not worked a  programmer and now I am taking this course by U of Waterloo that now asks that a program be written as above, but with ascii 32-127. I have not reached the function and memory stage yet. I have to get a simple program going that will print out in that order, line by line.

Comment: Do you understand what the problem you're having is? If not, try going line by line through your program and write on a piece of paper what you expect to see and compare it to what your program is producing.

Answer (score 0):

Not at all a pythonic or elegant solution by any stretch of the imagination, but building upon what you already have:

```
print('chr:',end='')
for asc in range(32,48):
    print('{:>4}'.format(chr(asc)),end='')
print()
print('asc:',end='')
for asc in range(32,48):
    print('{:>4}'.format(ord(chr(asc))),end='')
print()
print('chr:',end='')
for asc in range(48,64):
    print('{:>4}'.format(chr(asc)),end='')
print()
print('asc:',end='')
for asc in range(48,64):
    print('{:>4}'.format(ord(chr(asc))),end='')
print()
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why you are doing `ord(chr(asc))` in above code snippets. It simply means `asc` variable. Now, coming to your solution, you can first convert you `chr` and `ord` to string by using `str()` then you can apply `ljust()` or `rjust()` string methods. What they exactly do, you can know that from their documentation. Below is a code snippet:

```
for asc in range(35, 42):
    print(str(chr(asc)).rjust(5), end = '')
print()

for asc in range(35, 42):
    print(str(asc).rjust(5), end='')
print()
```